# i have an error while making an artificial assistant in python

Tags: python, pyaudio

i have an error with speech recognition and pyaudio but it's all installed

```
   PS C:\Users\giova> & C:/Users/giova/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe 
    "c:/Users/giova/OneDrive/Desktop/python/ai e assistenti/assistente tutorial pit pro/assis.py"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
        import pyaudio
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'
    AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
    PS C:\Users\giova> & C:/Users/giova/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe "c:/Users/giova/OneDrive/Desktop/python/ai e assistenti/assistente tutorial pit pro/assis.py"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
        import pyaudio
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\Users\giova\OneDrive\Desktop\python\ai e assistenti\assistente tutorial pit pro\assis.py", line 9, in <module>
        with Microphone() as source:
      File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
        self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
      File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
        raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
    AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

with this code :

```
from pyttsx3 import init
from speech_recognition import Recognizer, Microphone

engine = init()
engine.say("che cavolo vuoi")
engine.runAndWait()
r = Recognizer()

with Microphone() as source:
    print("pronto ad ascoltare...")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    testo = r.recognize_google(audio, Lenguage="it-IT")
    print(testo)
```

I am following an tutorial and idk why this error appears to me

Comment: Error says you need to have `pyaudio` installed. From the [project page](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition#requirements) for SpeechRecognition, they say that `pyaudio` is a requirement if you use a microphone.

Comment: i have installed it